# SSRS and Oracle data comparison

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, date, comparison

I have an SSRS report that uses the Date/Time parameter.  The value it produces is in the form

- 7/27/2011 10:17:00 AM

I am doing a comparison on my data table in Oracle but getting no results back.  The format of the date in the data table is

- 07/28/2009 12:00:00.0000 AM

The SQL Query is doing this comparison

- EXPIRATION_DATE <
  to_date('07/27/2011
  12:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')

I've tried several varieties of formatting but not having any luck.

Any Ideas?

Comment: could you use the odbc format ? yyyy-mm-dd-HH:mi:ss.mmm

Comment: try the '27/07/2011 12:00:00' date instead.

Comment: This works in Oracle...EXPIRATION_DATE < to_date('01/17/2010 12:00:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')  But does not work when I pass i nthe SSRS parameter.  i.e. EXPIRATION_DATE < to_date(:EXP_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')

Comment: It throws the error ORA: 01843 "Not a valid month"

Comment: You know, I have a sneaking suspicion that the reason this question isn't rated higher is that everyone gives up on it before they get this far. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out....

Use this mask in the Oracle SQL Query as the parameter looks 7/27/2011 10:17:00 AM :

- to_date(:EXP_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')

And replace the AM or PM from the SSRS paramater:

- =Parameters!Exp_Date.Value.ToString().Replace("
  AM","").Replace(" PM","")

Wow....who knew that the AM PM would throw a month error?  Also, I tried with the 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM' mask and still got the month error